# Extracting the Date Associated with Each URL

Tags: python, html, windows, date, web-scraping

I have been unable to extract the date from each URL because it the class "grid 3" is shared among many other attributes as well. Any sort of guidance will be greatly appreciated .

1) Python code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
.
k = requests.get("http://www.ign.com/tv/reviews")
b = k.text
asoup = BeautifulSoup(b, "html.parser")
.
f = asoup.find_all("div")
.
for item in l:
  print(item)
  print("--"*20)
```

2) HTML Code

```
<div class="grid_3">
  <div>December 5, 2016</div>
</div>
<div class="releaseDate grid_3 omega">
  <div class="scoreBox">
    <a class-"scoreBox-link" href="http://...">
    <span class-"scoreBox-score">7.3</span>
  <span class="scoreBox-scorePhrase">Good</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clear itemList-item">
<div class="grid_3 alpha">
  <a href="http://...">
  <img class="item-boxArt" src="http://..." alt="Home Again"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This question is unintelligible, where's the code? What is grid 3?

Comment: Edit in your code and we might actually be able to help...

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdjRC.png

Comment: For some reason , I am not being allowed to post more than 1 linl

Comment: @Legendary, I typed up the necessary code. But please copy and pasted your code in the future. You may need to restart your browser if it's bugging out.

Answer (score 0):

**Try with this:**

```
#coding:utf-8

import requests
from lxml import html

response = requests.get("http://www.ign.com/tv/reviews")
tree = html.fromstring(response.content)
items = tree.xpath('//div[@class="clear itemList-item"]')

for item in items:
    link, title = map(lambda x: x.strip(), item.xpath('.//div[@class="up-com grid_7"]/div[@class="item-title"]/h3/a/text() | .//div[@class="up-com grid_7"]/div[@class="item-title"]/h3/a/@href')) 
    date = item.xpath('.//div[@class="grid_3"]/div/text()')[0].strip()
    score_number, score_description = item.xpath('.//div[@class="releaseDate grid_3 omega"]/div[@class="scoreBox"]/a[@class="scoreBox-link"]/span[@class="scoreBox-score"]/text() | .//div[@class="releaseDate grid_3 omega"]/div[@class="scoreBox"]/a[@class="scoreBox-link"]/span[@class="scoreBox-scorePhrase"]/text()')
    print "Title: {}".format(title)
    print "Link: {}".format(link)
    print "Date: {}".format(date)
    print "Score: {} ({})\n".format(score_number, score_description)
```

**Results:**

```
Title: Dragon Ball Super - Champa's Challenge! This Time We Fight With Baseball!
Link: http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/12/13/dragon-ball-super-episode-70-achampas-challenge-this-time-we-fight-with-baseballa-review
Date: December 13, 2016
Score: 8 (Great)

Title: The Walking Dead - Hearts Still Beating
Link: http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/12/11/the-walking-dead-hearts-still-beating-review
Date: December 12, 2016
Score: 7.6 (Good)

Title: Ash vs Evil Dead - Second Coming
Link: http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/12/11/ash-vs-evil-dead-second-coming-review
Date: December 12, 2016
Score: 8.5 (Great)

Title: Star Wars Rebels - Visions and Voices
Link: http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/12/11/star-wars-rebels-visions-and-voices-review
Date: December 11, 2016
Score: 8.8 (Great)

Title: DC's Legends of Tomorrow - The Chicago Way
Link: http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/12/08/dcs-legends-of-tomorrow-the-chicago-way-review
Date: December 9, 2016
Score: 9.2 (Amazing)

Title: Supernatural - Lotus
Link: http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/12/08/supernatural-lotus-review
Date: December 9, 2016
Score: 8.3 (Great)

Title: South Park - The End of Serialization As We Know It
Link: http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/12/07/south-park-the-end-of-serialization-as-we-know-it-review
Date: December 8, 2016
Score: 6.6 (Okay)

Title: Arrow - What We Leave Behind
Link: http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/12/07/arrow-what-we-leave-behind-review
Date: December 8, 2016
Score: 8.9 (Great)

Title: Vikings - The Vision
Link: http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/12/07/vikings-the-vision-review
Date: December 8, 2016
Score: 7.8 (Good)

Title: The Flash - The Present
Link: http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/12/06/the-flash-the-present-review
Date: December 7, 2016
Score: 8.6 (Great)

Title: Dragon Ball Super - Goku vs Arale! A Ridiculous Battle Will End the Earth?!
Link: http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/12/05/dragon-ball-super-episode-69-goku-vs-arale-a-ridiculous-battle-will-end-the-earth-review
Date: December 6, 2016
Score: 6.5 (Okay)

Title: Westworld - The Bicameral Mind
Link: http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/12/04/westworld-the-bicameral-mind-review
Date: December 5, 2016
Score: 8.5 (Great)

Title: The Walking Dead - Sing Me a Song
Link: http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/12/04/the-walking-dead-sing-me-a-song-review
Date: December 5, 2016
Score: 7.3 (Good)

Title: Ash vs Evil Dead - Home Again
Link: http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/12/04/ash-vs-evil-dead-home-again-review
Date: December 5, 2016
Score: 9 (Amazing)

Title: Star Wars Rebels - An Inside Man
Link: http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/12/03/star-wars-rebels-an-inside-man-review
Date: December 4, 2016
Score: 8.8 (Great)

Title: DC's Legends of Tomorrow - Invasion!
Link: http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/12/01/dcs-legends-of-tomorrow-invasion-review
Date: December 2, 2016
Score: 8.8 (Great)

Title: South Park - Not Funny
Link: http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/11/30/south-park-not-funny-review
Date: December 1, 2016
Score: 8.6 (Great)

Title: Arrow - Invasion!
Link: http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/11/30/arrow-invasion-review
Date: December 1, 2016
Score: 8.7 (Great)

Title: Vikings - The Outsider
Link: http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/11/30/vikings-the-outsider-review
Date: December 1, 2016
Score: 8.5 (Great)

Title: Lethal Weapon - Can I Get A Witness?
Link: http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/11/30/lethal-weapon-can-i-get-a-witness-review
Date: December 1, 2016
Score: 7.2 (Good)

Title: The Flash - Invasion!
Link: http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/11/29/the-flash-invasion-review
Date: November 30, 2016
Score: 8.4 (Great)

Title: Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. - Deals with Our Devils
Link: http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/11/29/marvels-agents-of-shield-deals-with-our-devils-review
Date: November 30, 2016
Score: 8.3 (Great)

Title: Incorporated - Vertical Mobility
Link: http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/11/29/incorporated-vertical-mobility-review
Date: November 29, 2016
Score: 7 (Good)

Title: Dragon Ball Super - Come Forth, Shenron! Whose Wish Will Be Granted?!
Link: http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/11/29/dragon-ball-super-episode-68-acome-forth-shenron-whose-wish-will-be-granteda-review
Date: November 29, 2016
Score: 7.5 (Good)

Title: Supergirl - Medusa
Link: http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/11/28/supergirl-medusa-review
Date: November 29, 2016
Score: 8.4 (Great)
```